# producing a mollweide projection map with Pylab&Pyplot.Also,to annotation values of points will show

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, projection

I consider some observation studies as Daily.A program among these that

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

x = np.array([-93.690, -97.839, 105.193, -18.550, 166.095, -67.075]) # longitude
y = np.array([14.591, 2.011, -7.380, 68.075, -10.757, -24.041]) # latitude

degtorad = math.pi/180.
alpha = np.arange(-180,180.,1.)
alpha *= degtorad
x1 = np.sin(192.25*degtorad - alpha)
x2 = np.cos(192.25*degtorad - alpha)*np.sin(27.4*degtorad)
yy = np.arctan2(x1, x2)
longitude = 303*degtorad - yy
x3 = np.cos(27.4*degtorad) * np.cos(192.25*degtorad - alpha)
latitude = np.arcsin(x3)
xrad = x * degtorad
yrad = y * degtorad

fig1 = pl.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection="mollweide")
ax1.scatter(xrad,yrad)
ax1.plot([-math.pi, math.pi], [0,0],'r-')
ax1.plot([0,0],[-math.pi, math.pi], 'r-')
pl.title("before 27 Feb 12:00-after 28 Feb 24:00")
pl.grid(True)
pl.show()

    enter code here

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.gridlines()
plt.show()
```

carrying-out to figure as two apart.I wonder a annotation presentation for point values with one equivalent figure conclusion for two figure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqdH5.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBP5r.png)

Comment: This type daily analysis can express as a supply on shaping of geomagnetic modelling efforts as pfsspy.Thus,I especially would like to inform that David Stansby and other related programmers.Similar efforts thus I think that to important a impulsive power will cause

Comment: I think as other alternative for a solution on single figure of program that about  role of a ' image thrusting' type process  as similar  to subplot type tricks.Other ideas thus will be important